# Error occurred while changing is Identity to no in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, identity

I have to change the auto increment on ID to explicitly define ID. For this I Go to 
datatabse-> tables -> mytable -> design. There I set is dentity (under identity specification) to No. But when I click save it throws an error saying.

```
Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following tables to 
be droped and re created....
```

Is there any way to do it without dropping the table. I searched this error and got the solution to run a following query

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON GO
```

But when I try to insert from code, it throws error that

```
 Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'mytable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

Is there any way to get out of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once identity, always identity. You cannot change the identity property on a column. Technically, you *could* use `IDENTITY_INSERT` to get around it, but this requires setting the option on every single insert you do (this setting doesn't persist over sessions). This is probably not what you want.

Your only alternative, if recreating the table isn't an option, is to create a new column that isn't an identity column, then dropping the old one:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD NotAnID INT NULL;
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE MyTable SET NotAnID = ID;
    ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN NotAnID INT NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN ID;
    EXECUTE sp_rename 'MyTable.NotAnID', 'ID';
COMMIT;
```

This assumes your identity column is `NOT NULL` (as it usually is), that `ID` is not the primary key, that it isn't participating in foreign key constraints, and that you want the new column to take place of the old one.

If `ID` *is* the primary key, this exercise gets more involved because you need to drop the primary key constraint and recreate it -- which has its own challenges. Doubly so if it's also the clustered index. In this case, you are probably better off recreating the table anyway, because recreating the clustered index means the whole table is rewritten -- this will almost certainly interrupt production work, so you may as well let SSMS do the tough work for you. To allow that, go to Tools -> Options -> Designers and uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".

Comment: kindly elaborate this suggestion. "is to create a new column that isn't an identity column, then dropping the old one..." this might be useful

Comment: Done. I'm still not covering all possible cases (the column is the primary key, or participates in FK constraints, or is the clustered index). That gets increasingly more complicated.

Comment: So this solution is not recommended?

Comment: It's not a question of what's recommended, but a question of what works. Creating a new column and dropping the old one is possible in simple cases, but it may not be possible because of the constraints mentioned.

Comment: Yes you are right. it is not dropping because of constraints. Well thanks a lotJeroen